# How to I get the first directory from the PATH environment variable in bash?

Tags: bash

Assuming that your PATH environment variable contains a list of paths, separated by `:`, how do I get only the first folder from this list into another variable?

Comment: I just wonder why you never select one answer. That is the way we roll here, you know:[What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 10):

I assume you want to do it with a bash command. Try this:

```
echo ${PATH%%:*}
```

Comment: A brief explanation of how this works would be very useful.

Comment: This strips everything from PATH from the first : onward, leaving the first directory of PATH

Comment: Is there a similar solution to get the last entry from the PATH?

Answer (score 3):

How about using awk?

```
foo=`echo $PATH | awk -F':' '{ print $1}'`
```

Comment: Thanks! So far this was the only example that worked cross-platforms Linux and Mac OS.

Comment: This also works without bash extensions - if this is of any importance.

Answer (score 3):

One way to read first entry be using `read` with correct `IFS`:

```
IFS=: read firstPath _ <<< "$PATH"

echo "$firstPath"
```

You can also use `IFS` to populate an array and get any `Nth` position from array using index:

```
IFS=: read -ra arr <<< "$PATH"

echo "First entry: ${arr[0]}"
echo "Second entry: ${arr[1]}"
echo "Fifth entry: ${arr[4]}"
```

Another bash solution is stripping everything after first `:`:

```
firstPath="${PATH%%:*}"
```

Answer (score 3):

Either expansion:

```
mydir=${PATH%%:*}
```

Or read (bash 2.04+):

```
IFS=':' read -d '' mydir t <<<"$PATH"
```

Or better (bash 2.04+ also but not using a null delimiter):

```
IFS='' read -d ':' mydir <<<"$PATH"
```

are good solutions.

Comment: @RobinA.Meade Thanks, answer modified.

Answer (score 1):

So far I was able to get this using `MYDIR=$(sed 's/:/\n/' <<< "$PATH" | head -n 1)` but I would be happy to see a much nicer implementation.